# Checkstyle for Annotation

Tags: checkstyle

I want to create a checkstyle rule that enforces Annotations on a separate line except for function parameters and for each loops. Is there a way to create such rule, so that the following code will be valid:

```
@Deprecated
public class Annotation
{
  @Deprecated
  public void test(@Nullable String s) {
    @Rule
    Integer i;
    for (@Nullable Char c : s.getChars()) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know Checkstyle and can't help you, but I think it could be useful to add what language it is that you are analysing with it, because in general a language could have some syntax rules that must be taken into account when writing Checkstyle rules.

Comment: From [http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net) "Checkstyle is a development tool to help programmers write **Java** code that adheres to a coding standard."

Comment: Ok, thanks, I had just checked the description of the tag here on SO, and it doesn't mention that it is specific to Java. But, you're answering 10 months later? Wow!

Comment: I am not the owner of the checkstyle tag on SO, you may better ask the owner to provide a better description for the tag. IMO, the tag is descriptive enough for those who are aware of the checkstyle project to answer a question on SO and those who are not familiar with the project and can't help, to ignore it.

Comment: This off-hand remark that I should have ignored your question makes me think you are irritated by my comment. Well then, maybe you don't know that this site has a review mechanism, and that the first question asked by a new user is always reviewed because there's a high chance it can use some improvement. [That's how I found your post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/12034800). I left that comment because I wanted to help you.

Comment: Adding the Java tag was (and still is) a good idea, because it ensures the question is easier to search, and it is also seen by many more users (those who follow the Java tag). And more visibility also means more answers, and better ones. That's why I suggested to add the language. And by the way, your comment on Anakin's answer indicates that now CheckStyle has added a new feature that does exactly what you wanted: well, writing an answer to one's own question is allowed, and even encouraged. It will help all those who are trying to solve the same problem and find your question.

Comment: This discussion is quite off-topic and it was started by the initial comment that was not helpful at all. Adding Java tag to my question is not a good idea, as the question is *not* how to write Java code, but purely how to write Checkstyle rules. If you are interested to help, contact the owner of the Checkstyle tag and ask to clarify it. I would expect SO reviewers to provide valuable comments, while this thread is quite useless.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AnnotationLocation check, but looks like it is not possible now to create such a rule, as both `Integer i` and `Char c` are VARIABLE_DEF, so you can either enforce all variable definitions to have their annotations on a separate line:

```
    <module name="AnnotationLocation">
      <property name="allowSamelineSingleParameterlessAnnotation" value="false"/>
    </module>
```

or allow them on the same line:

```
    <module name="AnnotationLocation">
      <property name="allowSamelineSingleParameterlessAnnotation" value="false"/>
      <property name="tokens" value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF"/>
    </module>
```

However, it is a good idea for a new option for AnnotationLocation check. Please, create an issue for this: [issue tracking](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/issue-tracking.html), [How to request new feature for existing functionality?](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/report_issue.html#How_to_request_new_feature_for_existing_functionality).

Comment: It is now supported. See [https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/3117](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/3117)

Comment: @VladRozov Thanks for the tip. Any idea why I can't still specify `<module name="Checker"><module name="TreeWalker"><module name="AnnotationLocation"><property name="allowSamelineSingleParameterlessAnnotation" value="false"/><property name="tokens" value="CLASS_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF, METHOD_DEF, CTOR_DEF, VARIABLE_DEF, FOR_EACH_CLAUSE"/></module></module></module>` which fails due to `cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Token "FOR_EACH_CLAUSE" was not found in Acceptable tokens list in check com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.annotation.AnnotationLocationCheck`?